# C# - connecting to DB2 z/os mainframe without a license

Tags: c#, sql, .net, db2, mainframe

Problem:
I have a c# application that requires read and write access to DB2 z/os on mainframe.

I've searched around for weeks and came up with the conclusion: either go with IBM drivers (which requires a license file, or DB2 connect, or some sort of licensed software) or go with ole DB provider for db2 (host integration server) by Microsoft.

Microsoft option is free, just need to install the drivers, no need a license file. IBM option requires a DB2 connect software and a license (even if you use the ibm nuget package, it requires you to have the license file)

Questions:
1) can I do this for free meaning no license purchase? Aside from the Microsoft option?
2) is it possible to deploy the project to a machine without having to install any drivers? (Kinda like ibm's self contained nuget package) but you know, not requiring a license file?

Thanks in advance! P.S. the DB2 server is remote, not local

Comment: Not likely, and DB2 Connect is BIG $$$.

Comment: The most current versions (11 and 12) of DB2 on z/OS provide native REST capabilities.

Comment: @cschneid Thanks for that suggestion!  If life were that easy.....I'm actually working with DB2 for z/OS version 10......

Comment: End of support for DB2 for z/OS v10 was [2017-09-30](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=A375709J95876F78).  Are you certain you are working with DB2 for z/OS v10?

Comment: @cschneid actually my mistake! It's db2 v 11.1! Which means I can make the REST calls. But now I think I'm running into security problems. I've implemented a HTTPWebRequest post in my c# application but I'm getting the "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." Error. I've followed IBM's guide to creating a REST service but doesn't seem to work. Oh well, at least I know it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cschneid suggested, it IS possible to connect a c# application (or any a .NET application) to DB2 (Version 11 and up) for z/OS on mainframe through REST services.  You just end up requesting and getting responses via JSON objects.  You just need to make sure that DB2 is configured to handle REST calls (especially if you're using HTTPS)

Answer (score 1):

IBM-provided Db2 drivers always require proper Db2 Connect licenses to access Db2 for z/OS.
Those are not always costly, this totally depends on the environment and the requirements.

Microsoft’s drivers seem to be free, however, when using them, consider:

- the potential challenges when requesting the support from IBM - they will not agree to debug driver vs database interaction issues, and Microsoft will not help you unless you pay them;
- possible compatibility issues, including the lack of support for the latest functions and limited compatibility with newer Db2 fixes (even within the single major Db2 version).

If those two things are not really important for you in your specific situation, you can avoid the need to pay for Db2 Connect by using Microsoft’s drivers :-)

Comment: Actually, cscheind had a good suggestion with the REST services for DB2. This does not require any drivers installed with your .NET application :) but thank you for your response!

Comment: You have mentioned in the comment above that you use Db2 v11.1. Such version number is normally used for “Db2 LUW”, not “Db2 z/OS” software - even on the mainframe. If this is an LUW variant, you do not need Db2 Connect and associated license key - just use IBM-provided driver.

Comment: Nope, it's DB2 for z/OS, specifically version 11.1.0 https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=Y500397H59081K65